# Replace the label on a frequency plots

Tags: r, plot

I plotted a frequency table of a variable gender which is coded like this : female :2, male: 3.

In the plot, I see 2 and 3, but I'd like to put "Female" and "Male, without changing the value in the data.frame, because it would take more place.

How can I do that?

`plot(table4, main="Frequency table",xlab= "Gender", ylab="Country" )`

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code that you've already attempted?

Comment: Can you give more details? What plotting functions are you using? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, made some sample data and calculated frequency table with function `table()`.

```
 df<-data.frame(Sex=sample(c(2,3),10,replace=TRUE),Country=sample(c(4,5),10,replace=TRUE))
 table4<-table(df)
 table4
   Country
Sex 4 5
  2 4 1
  3 2 3
```

With function `str()` you can see structure of `table4`. `Sex` levels 2 and 3 are stored as dimension names. So you can replace them using function `attr()` and selecting `$Sex`.

```
 str(table4)
 'table' int [1:2, 1:2] 4 2 1 3
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ Sex    : chr [1:2] "2" "3"
  ..$ Country: chr [1:2] "4" "5"
 attr(table4,"dimnames")$Sex<-c("Female","Male")
```

Now plot changed `table4` object.

```
plot(table4,main="Frequency table",xlab= "Gender", ylab="Country" )
```

[image]